# Query builder can't find a column if rows are counted

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to see how many consecutive week had a record and encountered interesting behaviour

**This works**

```
    $weeks = $className::where($user_id_column, $user_id)
            ->where('created_at', '>', $period_start)
            ->select(DB::raw('WEEK(created_at) AS weeknumber'))
            ->groupBy('weeknumber')
            ->get();
```

**This throws error**

```
$week_count = $className::where($user_id_column, $user_id)
        ->where('created_at', '>', $period_start)
        ->select(DB::raw('WEEK(created_at) AS weeknumber'))
        ->groupBy('weeknumber')
        ->count();
```

`Unknown column 'weeknumber' in 'group statement'`

Why is that?

Comment: send output of the first `$weeks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is because `count()` will replace the select statement with `count(*) as aggregate`.

To achieve what you're after you can add the count in manually:

```
$week_count = $className::where($user_id_column, $user_id)
    ->where('created_at', '>', $period_start)
    ->selectRaw('WEEK(created_at) AS weeknumber, COUNT(*)')
    ->groupBy('weeknumber')
    ->get();
```